# Any way to wrap unformatted text in GitLab/GitHub flavored Markdown?

Tags: gitlab, github-flavored-markdown

For my project README.md file, I have CLI output examples.  I wrap these with a code fence:

````
    ```
    However, some of the lines are especially long and go on for quite a ways which makes them somewhat hard to read as you have to scroll to the right to read them. I would prefer these long lines get wrapped.
    ```
````

It looks like GitLab/GitHub flavored markdown support limited styling.  I'm trying to figure out if there's some clever way using pre/code or similar tags and limited styling to wrap the lines within the code fence or pre/code block.  I see this question has been asked before, but most of the answers are from sometime ago and I'm wondering if there are any new options in the last year or two?

For example, if you could use inline styling you could do something like this:

```html
<pre style="white-space: pre-wrap; word-break: break-word;">
However, some of the lines are especially long and go on for quite a ways which makes them somewhat hard to read as you have to scroll to the right to read them. I would prefer these long lines get wrapped.
</pre>
```

Of course that doesn't work.

GitLab also supports enabling HTML but this didn't work for me either:

```
{::options parse_block_html="true" /}
```

GitLab also supports using the code tag but I don't care for the formatting with this.  It wraps the lines but loses leading indentation and other spacing:

```
<code>
Long line...
</code>
```

Other things that failed:

````
<style>
  pre {
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    word-break: break-word;
  }
</style>

<style
   type="text/css">
.myclass1 {white-space: pre-wrap; word-break: break-word; color: darkblue;}
</style>

    ``` {.myclass1}
    ```

    ```
    Long line...
    ```
    {: .myclass-1 style="white-space: pre-wrap; word-break: break-word;"}

All the above tricks using <pre>...</pre> instead of ```...```
````